# Поиск оптимального набора мутация/образцы

Tags: c++, алгоритм, delphi, выборка, биоинформатика

В процессе разработке новой тестовой панели (тестовая панель - это инструмент для проверки пациента на определенное количество генетических мутаций, т.е. фактически, на возможность возникновения определенного заболевания у данного индивидуума) сталкиваешься с проблемой поиска оптимального набора сочетаний мутация/образцы. Опишу подробнее процесс подбора, чтобы было понятно (некоторые понятия я сильно упрощаю):

1. Из общей базы образцов создается выборка по родственным заболеваниям вида:

уникальное_имя_мутации (далее: **ИМЯ**) количество_заболеваний_вызываемых_этой мутацией (далее: **КОЛВО**) список_заболеваний (далее: **СПИСОК**)

```
cg26354493  449 1779260,1779264,1779276,1779288,1779303,1779305,1779306,1779312,1779314,1779315,1779321,1779322,1779342,1779437,1779441,1779444,1779469,1779489,1779491,1779497,1779498,1779500,1779501,1779502,1779544,1779545,1779549,1779551,1779553,1779556,1779562,1779594,1779601,1779636,1779638,1779644,1779645,1779647,1899592,1899594,1899596,1899597,1899598,1899622,1899627,1899628,1899629,1899630,1899633,1899635,1899636,1899637,1899638,1899639,1899642,1899643,1899646,1899647,1899648,1899650,1899651,1899657,1899664,1899666,1899740,1899741,1899765,1899766,1899768,1899769,1899770,1899777,1899779,1899780,1899781,1899783,1899784,1899785,1899788,1899789,1899793,1899795,1899798,1899799,1899800,1899801,1899802,1899804,1899805,1899807,1899808,1899810,1899811,1899812,1899816,1899817,1899818,1899820,1899822,1899823,1899824,1899825,1899826,1899827,1899828,1899829,1899830,1899831,1899832,1899833,1899835,1899836,1899839,1899840,1899841,1899842,1899843,1899846,1899847,1899848,1899849,1899851,1899852,1899853,1899857,1899859,1899862,1899863,1899864,1899866,1899868,1899869,1899874,1899875,1899877,1899878,1899880,1899885,1899887,1899889,1899891,1899892,1899896,1899902,1899905,1899909,1899911,1899913,1899916,1899917,1899922,1899924,1899931,1899932,1899933,1899934,1899936,1899937,1899939,1899940,1899942,1899944,1899945,1899963,1899964,1899965,1899966,1899968,1899969,1899970,1899971,1899973,1899975,1899976,1899977,1899978,1899981,1899987,1899990,1899991,1899992,1899994,1899995,1900018,1900019,1900022,1900023,1900024,1900025,1900026,1900027,1900028,1900030,1900031,1900033,1900034,1900035,1900036,1900037,1900047,1900049,1900050,1900051,1900052,1900053,1900057,1900058,1900059,1900060,1900061,1900063,1900065,1900067,1900068,1900069,1900070,1900073,1900074,1900075,1900076,1900078,1900082,1900087,1900088,1900090,1900095,1900098,1900099,1900100,1900101,1900102,1900103,1900104,1900105,1900106,1900109,1900111,1900141,1900142,1900143,1900144,1900152,1900153,1900155,1900156,1900157,1900159,1900160,1900162,1900164,1900165,1900167,1900168,1900169,1900172,1900175,1900176,1900177,1900179,1900181,1900182,1900187,1900188,1900190,1900192,1900194,1900197,1900198,1900200,1900201,1900202,1900203,1900204,1900205,1900206,1900208,1900209,1900210,1900214,1900216,1900217,1900218,1900219,1900226,1900227,1900228,1900229,1900230,1900231,1900232,1900234,1900236,1900237,1900238,1900239,1900240,1900241,1900242,1900243,1900246,1900248,1900249,1900252,1900254,1900255,1900258,2185755,2187686,2187687,2187689,2187690,2187691,2187692,2187693,2187696,2187697,2187699,2187701,2187708,2187709,2187710,2187711,2187713,2187717,2187718,2187719,2187723,2187724,2187726,2187728,2187731,2187732,2187734,2187735,2187736,2187737,2187738,2187739,2187742,2187743,2187745,2187748,2187750,2187751,2187752,2187753,2187754,2187757,2187758,2187759,2187760,2187762,2187763,2187764,2187769,2187771,2187772,2187773,2187774,2187776,2187780,2187781,2187782,2187783,2187784,2187785,2187786,2187787,2187788,2187789,2187792,2187793,2187798,2187799,2187800,2187803,2187805,2187812,2187813,2187815,2187819,2187820,2187821,2187822,2187826,2187827,2187829,2187830,2187831,2187832,2187833,2187835,2187837,2187839,2187840,2187844,2187845,2187848,2187850,2187855,2187857,2187860,2187866,2187868,2187872,2187873,2187874,2187876,2187881,2187882,2187884,2187886,2187887,2187888,2187889,2187894,2187896,2187897,2187898,2262699,2262701,2262702,2262704,2262705,2262706,2262905,2262906,2262910,2263054,2263055,2263056,2263057,2263058,2263162,2263163,2263164,2263244,2263245,2263324,2263325,2339214,2339216,2339217,2339218,2339545,2339547,2339791,2339991,2340135
cg13045134  420 1779257,1779259,1779260,1779264,1779276,1779288,1779300,1779306,1779311,1779312,1779314,1779315,1779322,1779342,1779437,1779439,1779441,1779444,1779445,1779468,1779469,1779487,1779489,1779491,1779493,1779497,1779500,1779501,1779543,1779544,1779545,1779549,1779551,1779553,1779558,1779562,1779578,1779594,1779601,1779607,1779636,1779645,1779647,1899592,1899593,1899595,1899596,1899598,1899622,1899627,1899628,1899629,1899630,1899633,1899635,1899636,1899637,1899638,1899639,1899641,1899643,1899645,1899647,1899648,1899649,1899650,1899651,1899657,1899661,1899662,1899663,1899666,1899668,1899705,1899739,1899764,1899765,1899766,1899767,1899769,1899770,1899777,1899779,1899780,1899781,1899785,1899787,1899788,1899791,1899793,1899795,1899798,1899800,1899801,1899802,1899806,1899808,1899810,1899811,1899812,1899818,1899820,1899822,1899825,1899826,1899829,1899830,1899832,1899833,1899836,1899840,1899841,1899844,1899846,1899847,1899848,1899850,1899851,1899852,1899860,1899862,1899863,1899864,1899866,1899868,1899869,1899870,1899872,1899873,1899874,1899877,1899878,1899880,1899887,1899889,1899891,1899892,1899894,1899901,1899902,1899905,1899909,1899913,1899916,1899917,1899922,1899923,1899924,1899931,1899932,1899933,1899936,1899937,1899938,1899939,1899940,1899941,1899942,1899944,1899945,1899963,1899964,1899965,1899966,1899967,1899968,1899969,1899970,1899971,1899973,1899974,1899976,1899979,1899981,1899983,1899984,1899985,1899986,1899987,1899990,1899991,1899992,1899995,1900018,1900019,1900020,1900023,1900024,1900025,1900026,1900027,1900028,1900029,1900030,1900031,1900032,1900033,1900034,1900035,1900036,1900037,1900047,1900049,1900050,1900052,1900053,1900055,1900059,1900060,1900061,1900062,1900063,1900065,1900066,1900067,1900068,1900069,1900072,1900073,1900074,1900076,1900078,1900079,1900080,1900083,1900086,1900087,1900088,1900089,1900090,1900091,1900093,1900096,1900098,1900100,1900101,1900102,1900103,1900104,1900105,1900106,1900108,1900109,1900110,1900111,1900141,1900142,1900143,1900144,1900154,1900155,1900159,1900162,1900163,1900166,1900167,1900168,1900170,1900172,1900175,1900178,1900184,1900185,1900187,1900188,1900191,1900192,1900194,1900195,1900198,1900199,1900200,1900201,1900202,1900203,1900205,1900208,1900210,1900214,1900218,1900222,1900223,1900225,1900226,1900227,1900229,1900231,1900233,1900234,1900235,1900236,1900237,1900238,1900239,1900240,1900241,1900242,1900243,1900244,1900246,1900248,1900249,1900252,1900254,1900255,1900257,1900258,2185755,2187686,2187687,2187688,2187689,2187694,2187696,2187701,2187708,2187709,2187710,2187711,2187712,2187713,2187717,2187718,2187726,2187727,2187728,2187729,2187730,2187734,2187735,2187737,2187740,2187743,2187744,2187745,2187746,2187747,2187751,2187753,2187754,2187757,2187758,2187761,2187762,2187763,2187764,2187765,2187766,2187769,2187771,2187772,2187773,2187776,2187780,2187782,2187784,2187785,2187786,2187787,2187789,2187792,2187798,2187799,2187800,2187801,2187803,2187807,2187812,2187813,2187815,2187817,2187819,2187820,2187822,2187826,2187827,2187830,2187831,2187833,2187840,2187845,2187846,2187850,2187855,2187857,2187861,2187864,2187865,2187866,2187867,2187868,2187870,2187873,2187874,2187875,2187877,2187882,2187886,2187893,2187894,2187897,2187898,2262699,2262706,2262905,2262909,2263054,2263056,2263057,2263058,2263162,2263164,2263244,2263325,2339214,2339217,2339218,2339548,2339791,2340135
cg18121066  416 1779256,1779257,1779259,1779260,1779264,1779276,1779288,1779300,1779306,1779309,1779312,1779314,1779437,1779439,1779441,1779444,1779469,1779487,1779489,1779491,1779493,1779497,1779500,1779502,1779543,1779544,1779553,1779558,1779562,1779594,1779601,1779607,1779645,1899593,1899594,1899596,1899598,1899622,1899628,1899629,1899630,1899633,1899634,1899636,1899637,1899638,1899639,1899640,1899643,1899647,1899648,1899649,1899650,1899651,1899657,1899661,1899662,1899663,1899665,1899666,1899668,1899739,1899741,1899764,1899766,1899767,1899769,1899770,1899772,1899778,1899779,1899780,1899781,1899782,1899783,1899785,1899787,1899788,1899789,1899791,1899795,1899798,1899800,1899801,1899802,1899804,1899805,1899806,1899807,1899808,1899810,1899811,1899812,1899818,1899820,1899822,1899825,1899826,1899828,1899829,1899830,1899832,1899833,1899836,1899838,1899839,1899843,1899844,1899846,1899847,1899851,1899852,1899860,1899862,1899863,1899864,1899866,1899868,1899869,1899872,1899873,1899874,1899876,1899878,1899880,1899885,1899887,1899889,1899892,1899901,1899902,1899905,1899907,1899909,1899911,1899923,1899924,1899932,1899933,1899934,1899936,1899937,1899938,1899939,1899940,1899941,1899942,1899944,1899945,1899964,1899965,1899966,1899967,1899969,1899970,1899973,1899974,1899976,1899978,1899979,1899980,1899981,1899983,1899984,1899986,1899987,1899990,1899991,1899992,1899995,1900018,1900020,1900023,1900024,1900026,1900027,1900028,1900030,1900031,1900032,1900033,1900034,1900035,1900036,1900047,1900050,1900051,1900052,1900053,1900055,1900056,1900057,1900060,1900061,1900062,1900063,1900064,1900065,1900066,1900067,1900068,1900069,1900070,1900072,1900073,1900076,1900077,1900078,1900079,1900080,1900083,1900085,1900086,1900088,1900089,1900091,1900092,1900093,1900095,1900097,1900100,1900101,1900102,1900103,1900104,1900106,1900108,1900109,1900110,1900111,1900141,1900142,1900143,1900144,1900155,1900156,1900158,1900159,1900160,1900162,1900163,1900164,1900165,1900167,1900168,1900170,1900172,1900173,1900174,1900175,1900176,1900184,1900185,1900187,1900188,1900192,1900194,1900195,1900198,1900199,1900200,1900201,1900202,1900203,1900204,1900205,1900208,1900211,1900212,1900214,1900216,1900222,1900225,1900226,1900228,1900229,1900232,1900233,1900234,1900237,1900238,1900239,1900240,1900241,1900242,1900243,1900244,1900246,1900248,1900249,1900254,1900255,1900258,2185754,2185755,2187686,2187687,2187688,2187692,2187693,2187694,2187696,2187701,2187708,2187709,2187711,2187712,2187718,2187720,2187722,2187727,2187728,2187729,2187730,2187731,2187732,2187733,2187734,2187735,2187736,2187737,2187739,2187740,2187743,2187744,2187745,2187746,2187749,2187751,2187752,2187753,2187754,2187757,2187758,2187760,2187762,2187763,2187764,2187765,2187768,2187769,2187770,2187771,2187772,2187773,2187776,2187781,2187782,2187784,2187786,2187787,2187792,2187793,2187798,2187799,2187800,2187801,2187812,2187813,2187815,2187817,2187819,2187820,2187821,2187822,2187826,2187827,2187829,2187830,2187831,2187834,2187835,2187837,2187838,2187840,2187845,2187846,2187847,2187855,2187857,2187861,2187865,2187866,2187867,2187868,2187873,2187874,2187875,2187877,2187884,2187886,2187894,2187897,2262704,2262706,2262904,2262905,2262906,2262909,2262910,2263054,2263055,2263056,2263057,2263058,2263162,2263164,2263244,2263324,2263325,2339214,2339217,2339218,2339548,2339791,2340135
cg24471254  407 1779255,1779257,1779259,1779260,1779264,1779276,1779288,1779303,1779306,1779309,1779312,1779314,1779315,1779319,1779321,1779322,1779342,1779437,1779439,1779444,1779468,1779469,1779489,1779491,1779493,1779497,1779498,1779501,1779502,1779544,1779545,1779549,1779558,1779562,1779594,1779601,1779636,1779645,1899592,1899594,1899596,1899597,1899598,1899622,1899628,1899629,1899630,1899633,1899634,1899636,1899637,1899638,1899639,1899643,1899647,1899648,1899649,1899650,1899657,1899660,1899661,1899663,1899664,1899668,1899739,1899764,1899765,1899766,1899767,1899769,1899770,1899777,1899778,1899779,1899780,1899781,1899783,1899784,1899785,1899788,1899793,1899795,1899798,1899799,1899800,1899801,1899802,1899804,1899806,1899807,1899808,1899810,1899811,1899812,1899818,1899822,1899823,1899824,1899825,1899826,1899828,1899829,1899831,1899832,1899833,1899836,1899839,1899840,1899844,1899846,1899847,1899848,1899852,1899853,1899857,1899859,1899863,1899864,1899868,1899869,1899873,1899875,1899877,1899880,1899887,1899889,1899890,1899891,1899892,1899901,1899902,1899905,1899909,1899911,1899913,1899916,1899917,1899923,1899924,1899931,1899932,1899933,1899934,1899936,1899937,1899939,1899940,1899941,1899942,1899944,1899945,1899963,1899964,1899965,1899966,1899968,1899969,1899970,1899971,1899974,1899975,1899976,1899977,1899978,1899983,1899984,1899985,1899990,1899991,1899992,1899994,1899995,1900018,1900019,1900021,1900023,1900024,1900025,1900026,1900027,1900028,1900030,1900031,1900032,1900033,1900034,1900035,1900036,1900047,1900049,1900050,1900052,1900053,1900055,1900057,1900059,1900060,1900061,1900063,1900065,1900069,1900070,1900073,1900075,1900080,1900086,1900087,1900088,1900090,1900093,1900095,1900101,1900102,1900103,1900104,1900106,1900108,1900109,1900110,1900111,1900142,1900143,1900144,1900153,1900155,1900156,1900157,1900159,1900160,1900162,1900163,1900164,1900167,1900168,1900172,1900173,1900175,1900176,1900177,1900179,1900180,1900181,1900182,1900186,1900188,1900192,1900195,1900197,1900201,1900202,1900203,1900204,1900206,1900208,1900209,1900211,1900215,1900219,1900222,1900224,1900226,1900228,1900230,1900234,1900237,1900238,1900239,1900240,1900241,1900242,1900243,1900244,1900248,1900249,1900251,1900252,1900255,1900258,2185754,2185755,2187686,2187687,2187688,2187689,2187690,2187691,2187692,2187693,2187694,2187696,2187697,2187701,2187708,2187709,2187710,2187711,2187713,2187715,2187717,2187718,2187719,2187724,2187726,2187727,2187728,2187729,2187731,2187734,2187736,2187737,2187740,2187742,2187743,2187745,2187746,2187751,2187752,2187753,2187754,2187757,2187762,2187763,2187764,2187765,2187766,2187768,2187769,2187771,2187772,2187773,2187776,2187778,2187780,2187781,2187784,2187785,2187786,2187787,2187788,2187792,2187798,2187800,2187801,2187803,2187805,2187807,2187812,2187813,2187815,2187817,2187818,2187820,2187827,2187830,2187831,2187833,2187835,2187837,2187840,2187845,2187846,2187848,2187850,2187855,2187857,2187858,2187861,2187864,2187866,2187868,2187872,2187873,2187875,2187882,2187883,2187886,2187889,2187893,2187896,2187897,2187898,2262699,2262701,2262703,2262705,2262706,2262904,2262905,2262906,2262909,2262910,2263054,2263055,2263056,2263057,2263058,2263162,2263163,2263164,2263245,2263324,2263325,2339214,2339217,2339218,2339547,2340135
cg27317046  390 1779257,1779259,1779264,1779276,1779288,1779303,1779305,1779306,1779309,1779312,1779314,1779315,1779319,1779342,1779437,1779439,1779441,1779444,1779445,1779468,1779469,1779487,1779489,1779491,1779493,1779497,1779500,1779501,1779543,1779544,1779549,1779553,1779558,1779562,1779578,1779594,1779601,1779607,1779636,1779644,1779645,1779647,1899593,1899594,1899596,1899598,1899622,1899627,1899628,1899629,1899630,1899633,1899634,1899635,1899636,1899637,1899639,1899643,1899647,1899648,1899649,1899651,1899657,1899661,1899662,1899663,1899664,1899666,1899668,1899739,1899740,1899741,1899765,1899766,1899770,1899772,1899777,1899779,1899780,1899781,1899782,1899786,1899787,1899788,1899791,1899795,1899798,1899800,1899801,1899802,1899804,1899805,1899806,1899807,1899808,1899812,1899822,1899825,1899826,1899828,1899829,1899830,1899832,1899833,1899836,1899838,1899840,1899841,1899843,1899844,1899846,1899848,1899851,1899860,1899862,1899863,1899864,1899866,1899868,1899869,1899872,1899873,1899874,1899876,1899878,1899880,1899887,1899889,1899891,1899892,1899901,1899902,1899905,1899907,1899909,1899911,1899913,1899916,1899917,1899924,1899931,1899932,1899933,1899934,1899936,1899937,1899940,1899941,1899942,1899944,1899945,1899963,1899964,1899965,1899966,1899968,1899969,1899970,1899971,1899972,1899973,1899974,1899975,1899976,1899977,1899978,1899981,1899983,1899984,1899985,1899990,1899992,1899994,1899995,1900018,1900019,1900020,1900023,1900025,1900026,1900027,1900028,1900029,1900030,1900031,1900032,1900033,1900034,1900035,1900036,1900037,1900047,1900050,1900051,1900052,1900053,1900055,1900056,1900059,1900060,1900062,1900063,1900065,1900066,1900067,1900069,1900070,1900073,1900075,1900076,1900078,1900079,1900081,1900082,1900086,1900088,1900089,1900090,1900101,1900102,1900103,1900104,1900106,1900108,1900109,1900110,1900111,1900142,1900143,1900144,1900155,1900156,1900159,1900162,1900163,1900167,1900168,1900172,1900173,1900174,1900175,1900176,1900181,1900185,1900188,1900192,1900193,1900194,1900195,1900200,1900201,1900202,1900204,1900205,1900206,1900207,1900208,1900209,1900210,1900215,1900216,1900218,1900219,1900220,1900222,1900226,1900228,1900229,1900232,1900234,1900235,1900237,1900238,1900239,1900240,1900241,1900242,1900243,1900246,1900248,1900249,1900252,1900255,1900258,2185754,2187686,2187687,2187688,2187689,2187690,2187691,2187693,2187694,2187708,2187709,2187710,2187711,2187712,2187719,2187728,2187729,2187730,2187731,2187734,2187735,2187737,2187739,2187740,2187743,2187744,2187745,2187746,2187749,2187751,2187753,2187754,2187757,2187761,2187762,2187763,2187764,2187765,2187768,2187769,2187771,2187772,2187773,2187776,2187778,2187781,2187784,2187785,2187786,2187787,2187789,2187792,2187798,2187799,2187800,2187801,2187803,2187812,2187813,2187815,2187819,2187820,2187821,2187822,2187827,2187829,2187830,2187831,2187836,2187837,2187840,2187845,2187847,2187848,2187857,2187866,2187868,2187870,2187873,2187875,2187876,2187886,2187893,2187894,2187897,2262699,2262702,2262704,2262706,2262909,2262910,2263052,2263054,2263055,2263056,2263057,2263058,2263162,2263163,2263164,2263244,2263324,2339214,2339217,2339218,2340135
```

Фактически, это текстовый файл из трёх столбцов, разделенных знаком табуляции, третий столбец которого содержит через запятую номера заболеваний в общей базе (не повторяются внутри одной строки, не обязательно сортированы). Файл сортирован по количеству заболеваний на мутацию в порядке убывания

[Пример такого файла](https://gist.github.com/vicontfreetime/efd293591227495294143c1462cdda52) (выложен кусочек, в котором всего лишь 400 с небольшим строк, на самом деле, для данной ткани - более 80 тысяч строк,  и для других даже больше).

2. Необходимо подобрать набор мутаций с числом N (от 8 до 24, в зависимости от того, какая панель создается), в котором заболевания были бы представлены максимальным числом. То есть, допустим, мы создаем панель на 16 мутаций, мы выбираем 16 строк, складываем все заболевания, исключая дубликаты, получаем число заболеваний. Необходимо найти такой набор из 16 строк, у которого это число было бы максимальным.

**Как это делается обычно сейчас.**

Обычно лаборатории берут N верхних строк и создают панель на основе такого набора. Некоторые утруждаются чуть больше, проверяя 2N верхних строк. Как показали пробные расчёты, можно промахнуться с максимальным числом заболеваний вплоть до 20% (а это много!).

Возникло желание всё-таки всякий раз находить оптимальный набор мутаций.

**Варианты алгоритмов**

***1. В лоб.*** Поскольку количество мутаций может достигать сотен тысяч, искать в лоб будет очень долго. Для рака груди и панели на 24 это, как я понимаю, C из 84372 по 24, будет считаться неизвестно сколько.

***2. Методом группировки.*** Ищутся пары в которых все заболевания различны. Можно создать промежуточный файл, который (возможно) пригодится для создания следующей панели. Затем поиск пар уже среди новых данных. Оценить надежность и эффективность алгоритма не получается :(

***3. Методом вычитания.*** Первая мутация берется "по умолчанию", как указывающая на максимальное количество заболеваний. Далее с ней по очереди складываются все остальные мутации по порядку, выбирается пара с максимальным количеством. Теперь с этой парой снова проводится подобная манипуляция, пока не достигнем N мутаций. Как я понимаю, самый быстрый подход, но тоже не понятна его надежность.

Есть идеи/решения?

Comment: 1) А какие реальные цифры для размерности файла из п.1 (т.е. количество мутаций, если я правильно понимаю). в примере там 408 строк. 2) Все ли заболевания из списка описываются числами? т.е. можно ли их хранить в числовом типе данных.

Comment: @goldstar_labs Ну, вот для рака груди - 84372, для рака матки, возможно, на порядок больше (точнее не скажу, далеко сейчас от БД). Да, их можно хранить в численном формате, поскольку номер = id в БД

Comment: Задача сводится к тому чтобы узнать сумма каких строк  имеет максимальное значение?..   Я могу и не правильно понять,  но  желательно знать что нужно (без лишных слов  по поводу мутаций и заболеваний)   коротко и ясно

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, как я понимаю задача сводится к выбору из N множеств такого набора множеств M, чтобы этот набор включал в себя наибольшее количество уникальных элементов

Comment: @goldstar_labs, спасибо за ответ. Не  уверен так ли это,  но  вы ответили коротко и ясно.  Если понять суть, то не думаю, что это сложная задача: просто нужно  написать класс, который читает, считает и сравнивает сумму и  для этого класса  определить оператор <

Comment: Т.е. грубо `select count(distinct x) from f(y1,y2,...yn)` где `у1 є [1...m]` `y1<>y2...` и т д. где n - константа от 8 до 24.

Comment: Я не уверен, что правильно понел задачу и по сему удалюсь

Comment: @goldstar_labs Да, вы описали задачу коротко и ясно :)

Comment: Ну... как вариант графы. Т.е. 2 но оставить дубли (если есть дубли по колличеству). Групировка - сортировка - вычёркивание, и операция повторяется для третьего уровня - и так пока не достигните уровней 8...24. Получится "дерево" с вариациями. Тогда думаю это будет надёжный метод.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_coverage_problem

Answer (score 1):

Я бы остановился на варианте 3.
Каждую мутацию мы описываем классом наподобие

```
class Mutation
{
   std::string name; // Имя мутации
   std::set<int> deseases; // Множество болезней, сопутствующих мутации
}
```

На первом шаге, после обработки файла мы получим массив мутаций, из которого надо выбрать N элементов, таким образом, чтобы N элементов содержали максимальное количество уникальных болезней.
Мне нравится вариант 3, т.к. он даст наиболее

1) Сортируем массив по размеру множеств болезней. Первый элемент массива, содержащий максимальное количество болезней выбирается в качестве первого элемента панели.

2) На этом шаге надо рассчитать количество оставшихся уникальных болезней  для каждой мутации. Т.е. для множество болезней каждой мутации надо сравнить с множеством болезней панели.
Для с++ это можно сделать функцией `std::set_difference`.

3) Добавить элемент с максимальным количеством уникальных элементов к панели. Новое множество болезней панели будет равно сумме множеств всех входящих в нее мутаций.

4) Пункты 2-3 повторять пока мы не наберем нужное количество элементов или не достигнем необходимого охвата по болезням (Мы же знаем общее число болезней во всех мутациях и знаем текущее число болезней в панели)

Минусы:

- Поскольку число мутаций может достигать сотен тысяч, процесс расчета панели будет крайне медленный, т.к. на каждой итерации мы сотни тысяч раз работаем со множествами.

Плюсы:

- Точность. Поскольку на каждой итерации мы пересчитываем все множества, то это будет самый точный способ по охвату уникальных болезней в панели.
- Процесс набора панели легкоконтролируем, т.е. на любой итерации мы видим сколько у нас болезней в панели, сколько осталось и можем приостановить процесс, если достигли нужной точности (Сомнительный плюс, т.к. остальные способы тоже легко контролируются:)
- Результаты вычислений на любом шаге могут быть сохранены для будущих панелей. Процесс расчета по сути необходим только 1 раз, когда собирается новая панель или обновляется список мутаций/болезней. Дальше можно использовать заранее рас читанные наборы панелей

P.S.
способ вычисления разницы между множествами можно ускорить за счет оверхэда по размеру множества, я не знаю как называется этот способ, но суть такова:
Пусть у нас всего существует N болезней, тогда множество болезней конкретной мутации можно описать `как std::vector<bool>[N]`, где N-й элемент вектора обозначает наличие данной болезни во множестве, т.е. `deseases[1779264] = true` - обозначает, что множество содержит болезнь 1779264, а `false` - не содержит.
Тогда операция вычисления разницы будет выглядеть как поиск всех элементов множества2, который равны true, но равны false во множестве1.
Операция слияния множеств - битовое или всех элементов.
Возможно это будет быстрее операций над классическими множествами.

P.P.S.
Что-то внутри подсказывает мне, что существует тривиальное решение на SQL, которое будет сразу выдавать требуемый набор мутаций для панели, но в sql я не силен

Полезные ссылки (по сути у нас всего два метода, слияние множеств и вычисление разницы):
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_difference/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_union/

Comment: Общее число вариаций заболеваний (собственно, 1779305 и 1779306, к примеру, - это не два разных вида рака, а два разных протекания одного, каждый  со своей спецификой) на данный момент приближается к 7 миллионам. Разумеется, для конкретной ткани их количество уменьшается, и можно просто определять словарь. Идея использовать битовые вектора интересна, под это дело можно попытаться прикрутить SIMD или даже OpenCL. Что же касается базы, она обновляется примерно раз в три месяца, поэтому, боюсь, для будущих панелей сохранять особо будет нечего.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov, для битовых векторов можно еще оптимизировать расчеты, если на каждой итерации вычеркивать существующие болезни из множеств и оставлять только уникальные, тогда мы будем ускоряться с каждой итерацией. Если вместо высокоуровневых векторов написать свой битовый массив как обвязку над куском памяти и реализовать для него логические операции (И/ИЛИ и проч), то получится быстро, 7 млн болезней это всего 854кБ битовый массив, молотить логические операции должно быстро на таких объемах